# Pkg.clone() changed on julia 0.5?

Tags: git, julia

On OSX El Capitan (I had same results with git 2.3 and git 2.7)

I clean everything

```
~/.julia $ rm -rf v0.4/*
~/.julia $ rm -rf v0.5/*
```

Then I run Julia0.5 and use `Pkg.clone`

The process stops and asks for "Private key location".

Providing wrong location gives an ERROR: 
`Private key not found`

Providing the correct location gives another ERROR:

```
GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:SSH, Failed to authenticate SSH session: Callback returned error)
 in macro expansion at ./libgit2/error.jl:99 [inlined]
 in clone(::String, ::SubString{String}, ::Base.LibGit2.CloneOptions) at ./libgit2/repository.jl:191
 in #clone#109(::String, ::Bool, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Nullable{Base.LibGit2.AbstractCredentials}, ::Function, ::String, ::SubString{String}) at ./libgit2/libgit2.jl:327
 in clone(::String, ::SubString{String}) at ./pkg/entry.jl:195
 in clone(::String) at ./pkg/entry.jl:221
 in (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#clone,Tuple{String}})() at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##2#3{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#clone,Tuple{String}}, ::String) at ./file.jl:59
 in #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N}) at ./pkg/dir.jl:31
 in clone(::String) at ./pkg/pkg.jl:151
```

Then I run Julia0.4 and use `Pkg.clone`

Everything goes fine and the package is cloned.

Does anyone know if Julia0.5 requires some additional ssh configuration?

Comment: Are you cloning a private package, and are you sure you have the right keys? You can try use https using `Pkg.setprotocol!` "http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/pkg/#Base.Pkg.setprotocol!"

Comment: Yes and yes I have the keys. otherwise it won't work in julia 0.4. by the way cloning also works with plain git. it only doesn t work in julia 0.5

Comment: Have you tried using https?

Comment: julia 0.5 now uses libgit2 for managing pkgs and there are some known issues see: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16041

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderMorley. You are right. That seems to be related since the error I get shows libgit2

Comment: did https work?

Comment: The local server I'm using only accepts authentication by keys.

Comment: One issue may be that if the connection times out while waiting for the user input, `libgit2` does not have a way to retry. Can you try this by pasting the path when prompted, so that the wait is reduced? Also, if you have control over the server, can you check if there are any logs on the server side? That may help debug this.